# transfer form data form user to database server of my website in php

Tags: mysql

i m developing a site in php and using a html form, the form is in one of the php page in my website what i want is that i want to get the user input which he entered in form and takes that data and store it in mysql database at backend. i have successfully done it on my local host but i don't know i can i do it on my website server or what all i nedd to change or add in my code here's my code....

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="adminsqll.php">

 S.No.: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="sno" type="number"><br>


  Subject: <br><textarea name="subject" cols="60" rows="5" ></textarea><br>
   Content: <br><textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="5" ></textarea><br>

     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

this is my sendtodb.php page

```
    <?php
 // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');
 if($con)
    {
   echo "connect";
   }
    /*

    $sno =$_POST['sno'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    mysqli_select_db($con,'univ');
   $sql="INSERT INTO news(Sno,subject,content,date) VALUES                ($sno,'$subject','$content',CURRENT_DATE( ))";

        // Execute query
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     {
     echo "inserted successfully";
      }
   else
      {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to change the credentials in `mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');` and select a database (eg. `mysqli_select_db($link, "test");`, where "test" is your database name).

I suggest you to put your database connection function in a separated file. You'll probably have to connect to your database in more than just a page, so you won't have to call `mysqli_connect` again. This way, if you change your credentials, you won't have to change it in all your files. For example :

```
<?php
// dbconnect.php

function dbconnect() {
   $dbhost = "localhost";
   $dbname = "test";
   $dbuser = "username";
   $dbpass = "password";

   $cn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Connection error !');
   mysqli_select_db($cn, $dbname) or die('Error while selecting database');

   return $cn;
}

// sendtodb.php
include "/path/to/dbconnect.php";

$con = dbconnect();
if ($con) echo "connected !";

// your code...

?>
```